# PHP and MySQL: 72 hours expiration for a task

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a site in PHP and MySQL where a person is assigned to do a task for another person. Time period allotted to complete the task is 72 hours.

If done, the other person will confirm so. If not, I want to take certain actions (like blocking his account, sending an email, assign the task to someone else etc.) What is the best way to do this?

As the count-down runs second-by-second, I guess I will have to run a script every second.

Comment: It will be good even if I can update couple of records in the DB at expiration.
If I could update a value that indicates time-out for the job and another value indicating free slot for task assignment, it will be more than enough. But I need this to be precise by last second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very few things have to happen truely immediately. If you've waited 72 hours for something to happen, having an action occur within a matter of a few minutes will not matter so much.

If you really do want something to happen so quickly, and you will always have a long time between potential events, one thing I would suggest is not using a cronjob, but something more akin to what @muc has suggested - a script that runs regularly within a shell script that will keep it going (just doing an 'exec $0' at the end to rerun the script when it would exit).

The script (in PHP for example) that checks the database doesn't have to be running all the time either. Whenever it finds something that is due to happen in more than a few seconds time, it sleeps till the next event is due to happen. When it wakes up, it can double-check that it is still required, and then performs the relevant job.

```
<?php
$jobId = whatToRunNext();
if (! $jobId) {
  exit;
}
$secsToNextJob = howLongToNextJob($jobId);
if ($secsToNextJob > 0) {
   sleep($secsToNextJob);
   if (! jobStillRequired($jobId)) {
      exit;
   }
}
doJob($jobId);
exit;
```

Wrap that in a shell sript that will keep it running, maybe with a small sleep in the bash script, and you'd be good - while not being in a very long-running, cpu-killing loop.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
I am considering cronjob running every minute or so.

Comment: That would not be a good idea. If the jobs could run longer than a minute, you'll end up with many of them running at the same time, which I've seen happen. It is not pretty.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a cronjob to check for the deadline and eventually send the email, block the account, etc...

Although, if you actually need a persecond precision, you might want to use a single process with an "infinite" cicle and some sleeps in between.

Answer (score 1):

If your server is from *nix family, you could use cron/crontab. See examples of usage at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto

Comment: Thanks for answering so quick!
But is it safe to run a script through Cron every second or so?

Comment: As Dainis Abols suggested, it's best to set the deadline time, down to seconds accuracy in some place. Then your cron will only fire once, when 72 hours have passed. If the user accomplishes the task earlier, you will use some standard PHP script to notify you.

In short, when the user obliges to do a certain task, you would create a new cron job for him, which will fire in 72 hours. That can be done by a PHP script. Example how to do it:
http://livecronjobs.com/how-to-set-cronjobs-using-php

Comment: But there will be multiple tasks running around simultaneously, initiated at different times. Like in an e-commerce site, where purchased items are to be delivered within a time limit. But the countdown stops if the buyer confirms the delivery in the mean time.

Answer (score 0):

If I needed to do something like that, I would probably go by these steps:

1. Create event and calculate deadline
2. Set up a cronjob to run at the deadline time
3. cronjob checks the event status and takes actions

I think this will be the most efficient way in doing it.

Comment: There will be many such tasks assigned to different people at different times. I need something automated.

Comment: Exactly, you can create short-lived cronjobs automatically.

Comment: Can you please give a link to something where I can learn how to do this?
Google is not showing anything on automatic creation of cronjobs.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to create a site in PHP and MySQL where a person is
>   assigned to do a task for another person. Time period allotted to
>   complete the task is 72 hours.

These could simply just be db vales

table_task

```
.id
.user_assigned
.strart_date
.end_date
.status
.desc
```

> If done, the other person will confirm so. If not, I want to take
>   certain actions (like blocking his account, sending an email, assign
>   the task to someone else etc.) What is the best way to do this?

This again, Admin panel of some form with a layout of assigned jobs,  the ''worker'' should be required to post a job as ''done'',  the ''admin'' can then confirm this.  This can all be managed via Values in the db ''table_task.status''

> As the count-down runs second-by-second, I guess I will have to run a
>   script every second.
>   ^-- server suicide

Run the cron ever hour at most.  If you have 1000 users.  Then this cron will run 1000 a sec

in an hour this is,  60000*60

If you need to display the time use some jQuery of some form. There are lots of clock scripts.